# Declaring the same object inside a for/foreach loop

Tags: c#, object

Is it alright to declare an object inside a foreach loop? My main method has a for loop that calls method1 that also has a for loop. I just want to change the setFileFolder value of the same object, is it ok to declare the same object again then change it's value?

Sample code:

```
string[] arrs = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", };

foreach(string arr in arrs)
{
    GetFile gf = new GetFile();
    gf.setFileFolder(arr);
    Console.WriteLine(gf.getFileFolder());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is OK to declare an object inside a loop if this is what your intention is. In this case, each iteration of the loop will create a new instance of `GetFile`.

You can move the declaration outside the loop to reuse the same object:

```
GetFile gf = new GetFile();
foreach(string arr in arrs)
{
    gf.setFileFolder(arr);
    Console.WriteLine(gf.getFileFolder());
}
```

Comment: What will happen if I have multiple instance?

Comment: @Blackator The instances will get released at the end of each iteration, and be garbage collected.

Comment: Even though I put the object outside the for loop, the method GetFile object resides will still be called by the main() multiple times because it loops the method. Can I make an object public?

Comment: @Blackator Again, if this is your intention, you can do that; perhaps `private` would make a better choice. You can also declare it in the `main`, and pass as parameter to the method that you call in the loop. However, this may be too early an optimization: if the profiler does not point to allocations of `GetFile` as a time sink, you can keep it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a common and normal thing to do.

The only problem would be if `new GetFile()` were a slow operation. Then you would want to declare it outside the loop to improve performance.

Comment: How about having multiple instance of it because of the for loop? Is it bad?

Comment: Under most circumstances, it wouldn't be bad. If declaring a new instance of `GetFile()` takes a lot of time or uses a lot of memory, then it could be a problem, but otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it. You can always refactor if it becomes a problem, but for now, I would go for what you find the easiest to read.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to instantiate GetFile X times.

I will work of course, but it is not clean

Comment: I have a for loop that calls method1. If I put the object inside the method1, it will be instantiated multiple times. I just want to change the object's setFileFolder value. Is there any workaround?